# Question about an introductory limits proof in beginning calculus

Tags: derivatives

A proof offered for the **derivative of a constant** is shown here:

https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/DerivativeProofs.aspx

[image]

My question is:  why is it "permitted" to indicate:

$$\lim_{h\to0} [f(x+h)] = c$$

It seems like a step is being skipped by implicating that $f(x)+h$ is actually $f(x)$ [ presumably since the function itself is a constant?]

Comment: $f(x+h)$=c since $f(x)=c$ is constant

Comment: There is no $f(x)+h$ in your screenshot. There is even no   $\lim_{h\to0} f(x+h)= c.$ There is only an expression containing $f(x+h),$ equal to the same expression where $f(x+h)$ has been replaced by $c.$

Comment: @AnneBauval yea - i just  corrected that

Comment: @SineoftheTime  Your comment nails my question: i had not been interpreting correctly.  feel free to make an  answer if not "beneath you" in terms of being so simple

Comment: (Follow up) There is only an expression containing $f(x+h),$ equal to the same expression where $f(x+h)$ has been replaced by $c.$ This is legitimate because $f$ of anything is equal to $c.$ Same for the replacement by $c$ of the other subexpression $f(x).$

Comment: @WestCoastProjects you can visualize graphically for example: $f(x+h)-f(x)$ is an increment long the $y$-axis, but since $f$ is constant, the increment is $0$ as $f(x)=c$ is parallel to the $x$-axis

Comment: @AnneBauval That's a reasonable explanation as well - either or both of you or SineoftheTime are invited to make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "$\lim_{h→0}f(x+h)=c$" in your screenshot. There is only an expression containing $f(x+h),$ equal to the same expression where $f(x+h)$ has been replaced by $c.$ This is legitimate because $f$ of anything is equal to $c.$ Same for the replacement by $c$ of the other subexpression $f(x).$